# Specular Shading Phong Model not working

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

I am trying to implement the Phong reflection model using GLSL 3.3. I have followed a tutorial for it, and although I have changed my code to match up what the tutorial has, I am still unable to create the effect. I have a weird spotlight effect coming from origin to wherever the light source is instead of any Phong reflection. Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
out vec3 Color;
out vec3 NormalCamSpace;
out vec3 EyeDir;
out vec3 PositionWorldSpace;
out vec3 LightDirCamSpace;
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform vec3 lightPos;

void main() {
    NormalCamSpace =(V*M *vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz;
    PositionWorldSpace = (M * vec4(position,1.0)).xyz;
    vec3 PositionCamSpace = (V*M*vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
    EyeDir = -PositionCamSpace;
    LightDirCamSpace = (V*vec4(lightPos, 1.0)).xyz + EyeDir;
    Color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0 );
}
```

And here is the frag shader:

```
#version 330
in vec3 Color;
in vec3 NormalCamSpace;
in vec3 PositionWorldSpace;
in vec3 EyeDir;
in vec3 LightDirCamSpace;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform float ambientIntensity;

out vec3 outColor;

void main() {
    vec3 n = normalize(NormalCamSpace);
    vec3 l = normalize (LightDirCamSpace);
    float cosTheta = clamp(dot(n, l),0,1);

    vec3 E = normalize(EyeDir);
    vec3 R = reflect(-l, n);
    float cosAlpha = clamp(dot(E, R),0,1);
    cosAlpha = pow(cosAlpha, 5);
    float attenIntensity = 1.0 + 0.01*distance(lightPos, PositionWorldSpace)*distance(lightPos, PositionWorldSpace);
    outColor = Color*cosTheta /attenIntensity+
    Color* vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) * cosAlpha/attenIntensity+
    vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) * ambientIntensity;
}
```

lightPos is in world space.

This is the [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/) if it's relevent. Everything works except specular lighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your shader is fine. The only thing that's missing is the check for `dot(n, l)>0` when computing the specular term, but it doesn't really matter. The problem is probably that your normals are wrong.

Here's what I get when using your shader. I set the diffuse color to red, and the specular color to green, which adds up to yellow at the specular highlight. Looks pretty ok to me.

[image]

I'd also like to note that `LightDirCamSpace = (V*vec4(lightPos, 1.0)).xyz + EyeDir;` is correct. But I think writing that as `LightDirCamSpace = (V*vec4(lightPos, 1.0)).xyz - PositionCamSpace;` makes it clearer.

By the way, instead of `distance(lightPos, PositionWorldSpace)*distance(lightPos, PositionWorldSpace)` you should use

```
vec3 lightVec = lightPos - PositionWorldSpace;
float attenIntensity = 1.0 + 0.01 * dot(lightVec, lightVec);
```

Also, [lighting in view space is fine, there's no need to do it in world space.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499976/why-do-you-use-camera-space-instead-of-model-space-for-normals)

Comment: I have tried setting R = reflect(l,n), however it just makes the spotlight look backwards. Here is a picture of the effect: http://i.imgur.com/E2ngBiH.png I was also unable to get the abs(dot) instead of distance, because it got me a vertical ray of light, like so (highlighted in green by me): http://i.imgur.com/ySGpJhl.png Funny, I also asked that question about view space/world space.

Comment: Ah, after your edit the attenuation works as it is supposed to. The first issue is still present.

Comment: Funny indeed. :) Could you post a picture of your normals please? `NormalCamSpace = normal` and `outColor = normalize(NormalCamSpace)` and/or `outColor = normalize(-NormalCamSpace)`.

Comment: One makes the surface full green and the other full black(the negative one).

Comment: Alright, so the normals are (0,1,0) everywhere. Is that correct? How is your surface oriented?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is a simple 2 triangle square, oriented facing up, counter clockwise.

Comment: Oh my god I feel like a moron. Apparently I was supplying the model matrix for both the V and the M. I am so sincerely sorry for this.

Comment: Glad you found it. I was kinda running out of ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the world space of the normal and light direction vectors, not the view space. Think of it as comparing two vectors in 3D space, it doesn't matter where you are viewing from, the normals and light directions don't change.

Edit: another issue

```
    LightDirCamSpace = (V*vec4(lightPos, 1.0)).xyz + EyeDir;
```

The light direction should be the light position minus the vertex position (the vector going from the vertex to the light), again in world space. Should be

```
    LightDirCamSpace = lightPos - PositionWorldSpace;
```

**CORRECTION:** Disregard this, you can calculate lighting in either view space or world space, sorry for the misinformation, check out the other answer.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work as it is supposed to at all now. The weird spotlight effect is still there, and now the attenuation doesn't work correctly.

Comment: The [`inverse-transpose`](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html) of the 'modelview'.

Comment: I don't have non uniform scaling, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Found another issue and made an edit, check it out above. Also, if the problem is still persisting, could you show a screenshot of the "weird spotlight effect"?

Comment: Eyedir is = -PositonWorldSpace, so they accomplish the same thing. Here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/BBoArEv.png

Comment: Eyedir is = -PositionCamSpace (not -PositionWorldSpace) in the code you posted

Comment: My bad, I changed that. Still the same issue as in the screenshot.

Comment: Here is the code as it stands : http://pastebin.com/hfQPheuB. I didn't change any variable names yet.